# XSL-FO generating index in document

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to create an index in the beginning of the document. I know my xml structure and I have something like this

```
<div type="letter" xml:id="L.697">
```

What i want to try is to generate an index in an `fo:list-block` where I can add the reference to the specified location in the document which is accessible by clicking the new generated link in a generated lis. It should look like this.

1. Part1
2. Part2
3. .....

In XSL I solved it with: In the body: 
`<li> <a href="#{@xml:id}"> </a> </li>`
In the template: 
`<div class="letter" id="{@xml:id}">`

Do you have an idea, this would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FO equivalent for producing your links would be:

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@xml:id}>...</fo:basic-link>
```

and

```
<fo:block id="{@xml:id}">...</fo:block>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_basic-link

If you're using Antenna House, you could use `xml:id` instead of `id` in your FO if you want.

Comment: i agree with the solution, it is working fine, thank you